# Differences between two scripts with the same functionality (Express.js / Node.js / EJS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am taking a course and it included an exercise in which I was asked to:

1. Create an index.ejs file containing an h1 and two inputs for first name and last name (form)
2. In an index.js file, take the first and last name values from the form (POST request)
3. Count the total letters of the full name
4. Change h1 showing "Your full name is xxx letter long."

Using Express.js, Node.js and EJS for passing data.

This is the solution developed by **me**:

- *index.ejs*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Name Letters</title>
</head>

<body>
  <% if (!countLetters) { %>
    <h1>Enter your name here!</h1>
  <% } else { %>
    <h1>There are <%= countLetters %> letters in your name.</h1>
  <% } %>
  
  <form action="/submit" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First name">
    <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last name">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

- *index.js*

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(logger);

let countLetters = 0;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs", {countLetters: countLetters});
});

app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
  const firstName = req.body.fName;
  const lastName = req.body.lName;
  countLetters = firstName.length + lastName.length;
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

function logger(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Request: " + req.method + " " + req.url);
  next();
}
```

The solution is working and does not generate any type of error (I also tried to add a middleware that logs the HTTP request and the related URL), but it is different from the one proposed by the teacher.

This is the solution developed by **the teacher**:

- *index.ejs*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Name Letters</title>
</head>

<body>
  <% if (locals.letterNumber) { %>
    <h1>There are <%= letterNumber %> letters in your name.</h1>
    <% } else { %>
      <h1>Enter your name below </h1>
      <% } %>
        <form action="/submit" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First name">
          <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last name">
          <input type="submit" value="OK">
        </form>
</body>

</html>
```

- *index.js*

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
  const numLetters = req.body["fName"].length + req.body["lName"].length;
  res.render("index.ejs", { numberOfLetters: numLetters });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Leaving aside some small differences, such as the use of bodyParser instead of express or the fact that he didn't create a logger() function (which is convenient for me)...

...I would like to know why he handled requests/responses (app.get() and app.post()) like that?

Wasn't it more convenient and intuitive to do what I tried to do?

Any response that can clarify my ideas is appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: Purely a matter of coding style and opinion. *edit* — except I agree with your decision to use a redirect, which will leave the browser at the original URL.

Comment: You didn't consider two people accessing the page simultaneously. Which, for a web server, should be assumed to be a possibility. Your teacher handles the case where two people access the page simultaneously by not using a global variable. An equally valid solution is to store the variable in a session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach has a flaw in it as it's changing a global variable `countLetters`. As this is global, it's used by all requests that are made to your express server. That means that once you have set the letter count for one request, if someone else makes a GET request for your page to `/`, then your server will pull the `countLetters` value that was set via the previous request and display that. You should notice this if you open a new tab, or refresh the `/` page, both should continue to display the old `countLetters` that you had previously set.

By computing the count letter logic in the `POST` call using `req.body`, and passing through the values to `.render()` from there, you're ensuring that you're rendering using the data associated with that particular POST request, and not a different one.